# How to fix "Invarient Violation: AppRedux(...): nothing was returned from render. "

Tags: react-native

[image]

```js
//App.js

import {createDrawerNavigator,createAppContainer} from 'react-navigation'
import Homescreen from './src/pages/homeSceen/Home'
import Userscreen from './src/pages/User';
import Login from './src/pages/login/login'

const MyDrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator({
  login:Login,
  Home:Homescreen,
  Users:Userscreen
},{
  drawerType:'slide'
});

export default createAppContainer(MyDrawerNavigator);
```

```js
import {AppRegistry} from 'react-native';
import App from './App';
import React from 'react'
import Provider from 'react-redux'
import {createStore,applyMiddleware} from 'redux'
import promiseMiddleware from 'redux-promise'
import reducers from './src/store/reducers'
const createStoreWithMiddleware= applyMiddleware(promiseMiddleware)(createStore)
const AppRedux=()=>{
    <Provider store= {createStoreWithMiddleware(reducers)}>
    <App/>
    </Provider>
    
}
AppRegistry.registerComponent('react01',()=>AppRedux);
```

I was adding redux into my login app, for that, I used provider into a working app suddenly this error occurred.

I also tried

```
 import {AppRegistry} from 'react-native';
 import App from './App';
 import React from 'react'
 import Provider from 'react-redux'
 import {createStore,applyMiddleware} from 'redux'
 import promiseMiddleware from 'redux-promise'
 import reducers from './src/store/reducers'
 const createStoreWithMiddleware= applyMiddleware(promiseMiddleware)(createStore)
 const AppRedux=()=>{
     <Provider store= {createStoreWithMiddleware(reducers)}>
     <App/>
     </Provider>

 }
 AppRegistry.registerComponent('react01',()=>AppRedux);
```

expected successful build but resulted in an error.

Comment: Try to call your AppRedux function:
AppRegistry.registerComponent('react01',()=>AppRedux());
or
AppRegistry.registerComponent('react01',AppRedux);

Comment: AppRegistry.registerComponent('react01',()=>AppRedux()) resulted in error 'undefined is not an object(eveluating 'RootComponent.prototype')'

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to put `return` on your `AppRedux` function

```js
const AppRedux=()=>{
    return (
    <Provider store= {createStoreWithMiddleware(reducers)}>
    <App/>
    </Provider>
    )
}
```

Comment: already tried and resulted in error ' Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected
a string (for built-in components) or a class/function
(for composite components) but got: undefined. You
likely forgot to export your component from the file
it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and
named imports.'

Comment: Its error because you need to wrap the App container with React component, see here: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/app-containers.html

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
const AppRedux = () => {
   <Provider store= {createStoreWithMiddleware(reducers)}>
      <App/>
   </Provider>
}
```

To:

```
const AppRedux = () => ( 
   <Provider store= {createStoreWithMiddleware(reducers)}>
      <App/>
   </Provider>
)
```

And register must be like:

```
AppRegistry.registerComponent('react01', () => AppRedux);
```

Comment: resulted error "Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built in components) or a class/function (for composite components ) but got: object"